# How do I make a function use a variable that was declared on another function JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a var named `inimigo` that is declared in function of a `setInterval()` but on another function named `checkcolisions` I want to get the positions of the `inimigo` so I can check the collision with him and bala where i can get the position of `bala` by declaring the function after the animate as you can see. After many tries, the `ckeckcolision` always says `inimigo` is not defined". How can I get the position of `inimigo` and check the collision with `bala`'s position? If you have better ways to check the collision between the two please let me know, I will really accept them. Thanks for your time.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {

        var kp = e.keyCode;
        var carro = $("#carro");
        var bala = $("#bala");
        e.preventDefault();



        if (kp === 37 && carro.position().left > -500) {
            carro.css("left", (carro.position().left - 7) + "px");
        }

        if (kp === 39 && carro.position().left < 350) {
            carro.css("left", (carro.position().left + 7) + "px");
        }

        if (kp === 32) {

            bala.show();
            bala.css('left', (carro.offset().left + 67) + "px");
            bala.css('top', (carro.offset().top - 20) + "px");


            bala.animate({
                "top": "-=100px"
            }, "fast", checkCollisions);

        }
    });

    var counter2 = 0;
    var j = setInterval(function() {


        var inimigo = $(".inimigo").clone();
        $('.jogo2').html(inimigo);

        inimigo.css('left', (Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 550));
        inimigo.css('top', "150px");



    }, 2000);

    function getPositions(disparo) {
        var $disparo = $(disparo);
        var pos = $disparo.position();
        var width = $disparo.width();
        var height = $disparo.height();
        return [
            [pos.left, pos.left + width],
            [pos.top, pos.top + height]
        ];
    }

    function comparePositions(p1, p2) {
        var x1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
        var x2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
        return x1[1] > x2[0] || x1[0] === x2[0] ? true : false;
    }


    function checkCollisions() {
        var disparo = inimigo;
        var pos = getPositions(disparo);

        var pos2 = getPositions(this);
        var horizontalMatch = comparePositions(pos[0], pos2[0]);
        var verticalMatch = comparePositions(pos[1], pos2[1]);
        var match = horizontalMatch && verticalMatch;
        if (match) {

            alert("score +1");
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a variable in an outer context that is accessible by both functions:

```
var inimigo = null;
var counter2 = 0;
var j = setInterval(function() {
  inimigo = $(".inimigo").clone();
  $('.jogo2').html(inimigo);
  inimigo.css('left', (Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 550));
  inimigo.css('top', "150px");
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define inimigo variable globally so that you can access it any of the function. Whenever any function will access that variable, the recently changed value will be taken in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can have global variables. If you want to access method specific variable you can try this example  e.g.`

```
function y(){
    var x = 10;
    return { 
        get : function(){ 
                return x;
            } 
    } 
}
```

` 
and you can access  like

y().get();